# Double integral over carved circular disc [Answered in comments]

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Compute $$\iint_D \ln(1+x^ 2+y^2) \,dx\,dy, \, D= \{(x,y); 1 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 2\} $$**
Looks like standard integrals to me. I change to polar coordinates and we get $$\iint_E r\ln(1+r^2) \, dr\,d\theta, \, E= \{1\leq r \leq 2, \, 0\leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \} $$
and since the boundaries for $r$ and $\theta$ are parallel with the axes, we can write the integrals as  $$\int_0^{2 \pi} d \theta \cdot \int_1^2 r\ln(1+r^2) \, dr = \left\{1+r^2=t, dr = \frac{dt}{2r}\right\} = 2 \pi \frac{1}{2} \int_2^5 \ln(t) \,dt = \pi [t(\ln t -1)]^5_2 = \pi (5(\ln5 -1)-2(\ln2 -1)) = \pi (5\ln5-2\ln2-3)$$
but the answer sheet says the answer is $\pi \left(\ln \frac{27}{4}-1\right)$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: should it not be $ 1 \leq r \leq \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @RogelioMolina Oh yes of course, thanks for the very quick answer.